# Trying to figure out how to iterate a list twice in a One function

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to iterate over `fn` to modify the list again with only even numbers, AFTER appending. The desire result is

`[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]`

is this possible? I do not want to add `fn + sn` or `lst + lst2`. I want to continue over this specific function.

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]


def even(fn,sn):
    for i in sn:
        if i %2 ==0:
            fn.append(i)
        

even(lst,lst2)
print(lst) # output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

I know there are more efficient and pythonic ways like this example:

example 1:

```
def even2(fn,sn):
    fn[:] = [x for x in fn + sn if x % 2 == 0]
```

example 2:

```
def even(fn, sn):
    fn.extend(sn)
    fn[:] = [x for x in fn if x % 2 == 0]



def even(fn,sn):
    for i in sn:
        if i %2 ==0:
            fn.append(i)
            fn = list(filter(lambda x: x %2 == 0, fn))
```

the last code block is what i tried and failed with

Comment: *why* don't you want to just add them together? Or at least + them together into a temporary variable? Can you not just have your even() function return something and have lst = even(lst,lst2) ?

Comment: As i stated in my question i do not want to add them, i know already how that works, i am just trying to figure out all different ways on getting the same results.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to rebuild the entire list; just `extend` it with the desired extra elements.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> lst2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> def even(fn, sn):
...     fn.extend(i for i in sn if i % 2 == 0)
...
>>> even(lst, lst2)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

In the above expression `i for i...` is a *generator expression* that allows `extend` to iterate over all of the `i` elements without storing them in a separate list first.

Comment: This does not match the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps:

1. remove odd numbers from fn
2. extend fn with the even numbers in sn

This function does it without creating any temporary copies or sublists:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

def even(fn,sn):
    for i,n in enumerate(reversed(fn),1-len(fn)): # delete odds backwards 
        if n%2: del fn[-i]                        # so indexes stay stable 
    fn.extend(n for n in sn if n%2==0)            # extend with sn's evens
    
even(lst,lst2)
print(lst)
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

*Note that you could extend fn first and then remove the odd numbers, but that would be inefficient:*

```
def even(fn,sn):
    fn.extend(sn)                                 # add all sn values
    for i,n in enumerate(reversed(fn),1-len(fn)): # delete odds backwards 
        if n%2: del fn[-i]                        # so indexes stay stable
```

A more efficient way would be to iterate through the two lists and assign the result to fn[:].  Doing this starting with fn will ensure that there is no conflict between the iterators and the assignment process:

```
def even(fn,sn):
    fn[:] = (n for L in (fn,sn) for n in L if n%2==0)
```

*The nested comprehension loops allow iterating through the two lists without actually concatenating them so there is no temporary copies or sublists in that solution either.*

Answer (score -1):

Does this meet your requirements? Pulling `lst` into the `even()` func as a global.

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lst2 =[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
def even(fn, sn):
    global lst
    lst = [x for x in (fn + sn) if x % 2 == 0]

even(lst,lst2)
print(lst)
```

Comment: This is a huge step down from using `fn[:] = ...` -- now the function can only ever work if the first argument is called `lst` in the calling scope.

Comment: The question is horrifically written tbh